# wifi driver intel centrino problem

Tags: wireless, drivers, intel, centrino

I am having intel centrino wireless n 2230 card which i have trying to install through iwlwifi*.tar and then copying .ucode to firmware and then running modprobe twice but it wasnt available even i rfkill unblock all or by making ifconfig wlan0 up, pressing the wifi buttons etc it didnt work. I also updated the compat-wireless drivers but still all in vain... i also rebooted my pc for the above to work but it didnt.... i have been doing this for the last many days but i m not able to make my wifi work....
i m using hp pavillion m6, which is having intel centrino n-2230 wireless card.
If anyone can help please do email me. Thankyou.

Comment: airmon-ng gives me nothing....!

Comment: Welcome to Ask Ubuntu! It's difficult to tell what is being asked here. This is ambiguous, vague, incomplete, overly broad or rhetorical and cannot be reasonably answered in its current form. Please be a little bit more specific or detailed about whay you're trying to accomplish, or take a look at [What kind of questions should I not ask here?](http://askubuntu.com/faq#dontask)